# Angular Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 6 and I want to implement the dynamic addition of components according to the [instructions](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), but I get an error: **"Cannot read property 'create' of undefined."**

**component.html**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>...</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <ng-template answerHost></ng-template>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(AnswerHostDirective) answerHost: AnswerHostDirective;
private stepAnswerType1: ComponentFactory<StepAnswerType1Component>;
private stepAnswerType2: ComponentFactory<StepAnswerType2Component>;
private stepAnswerType3: ComponentFactory<StepAnswerType3Component>;

/* ... */

changeStep(id: number) {
    let viewContainerRef = this.answerHost.viewContainerRef;

    let componentRef;
    if (this.step.type == 1) {
      componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.stepAnswerType1);
    }
    if (this.step.type == 2) {
      componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.stepAnswerType2);
    }
    if (this.step.type == 3) {
      componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.stepAnswerType3);
    }
}
```

**directive**

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[answerHost]'
})
export class AnswerHostDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

I tried to replace the directive with a reference to the component's id, but I get the same error.
**component.html**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>...</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <ng-template #answerContainer></ng-template>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('answerContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) answerContainer: ViewContainerRef;
private stepAnswerType1: ComponentFactory<StepAnswerType1Component>;
private stepAnswerType2: ComponentFactory<StepAnswerType2Component>;
private stepAnswerType3: ComponentFactory<StepAnswerType3Component>;

/* ... */

changeStep(id: number) {
    if (this.step.type == 1) {
      componentRef = this.answerContainer.createComponent(this.stepAnswerType1);
    }
    if (this.step.type == 2) {
      componentRef = this.answerContainer.createComponent(this.stepAnswerType2);
    }
    if (this.step.type == 3) {
      componentRef = this.answerContainer.createComponent(this.stepAnswerType3);
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

**Fixed**
I updated part of the code.
component.ts

```
import { StepAnswerType1Component } from './step-answer-type1/step-answer-type1.component';
import { StepAnswerType2Component } from './step-answer-type2/step-answer-type2.component';
import { StepAnswerType3Component } from './step-answer-type3/step-answer-type3.component';

/* some code */

@ViewChild('answerContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) answerContainer: ViewContainerRef;

/* some code */

changeStep(id: number) {
    let componentRef, componentFactory;
    if (this.step.type == 1) {
      componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(StepAnswerType1Component);
    }
    if (this.step.type == 2) {
      componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(StepAnswerType2Component);
    }
    if (this.step.type == 3) {
      componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(StepAnswerType3Component);
    }
    componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
 }
```

Comment: Try changing ng-template with ng-container

Comment: The same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are calling this method 'changeStep' inside 'ngAfterViewInit()'.

Comment: I tried to call the method changeStep from ngOninit and ngAfterViewInit. The result is the same.

Comment: created a stack overflow and its working fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-eefxju

Comment: Notice I'm using createComponent and Angular 6. Your example is CreativeEmbededViev and Angular 2.

Comment: I am able to access all the public Method available for ViewContainerRef Instance Class. i.e clear(), createEmbeddedView(). Also createComponent() will also work.

Comment: In the development environment, I also get access to these methods. An error occurs during execution.

Comment: I have updated stackblitz with createComponent method